# regex extract groups by transaction date, merchant and amount

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a list of transactions like the following:

Dec 21, 2019
Debit card credit received from

PayPal Debit Card

Completed

$1.85 USD

$0.00

$1.85

Oct 31, 2019
Debit Card pin purchase to

72.21.207.65 ,AMAZON.COM*MI8XP9SP3,SEATTLE,WA,US

Completed

-$26.57 USD

$0.00

-$26.57

Oct 7, 2019
Debit card ATM withdrawal

PayPal

Completed

-$187.20 USD

-$1.50

-$188.70

I would like to use regex to parse it to:
Dec 21, 2019; PayPal Debit Card;  $1.85 USD
Oct 31, 2019; AMAZON.COM*MI8XP9SP3,SEATTLE,WA,US; -$26.57 USD
Oct 7, 2019; PayPal; -$188.70

I am a total regex newbie, but I know it can be done.

All help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is pretty close.  You'd have to fill in the other month prefixes in the alternations of course. I added the group names for clarity.

pattern:

`.*?(?<date>(?:dec|oct).*?$)\n^.*?$\n^.*?$\n(?<method1>^.*?$).*?(?<amount>-?\$.*?$)(?:(?!(?:dec|oct)).)+`

sub:

```
$1 $2 $3
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/OGqMkL/1/)

Comment: I'm trying the method you suggest, however when adding month abbreviations to the date group(?:dec|oct) like (?:dec|oct|sep|aug|jul) it won't parse these dates.   Am I missing something? https://regex101.com/r/OGqMkL/3

Comment: seems to work with all the prefixes, see https://regex101.com/r/OGqMkL/2.  are you sure case insensitive matching is turned on?

Comment: Ok, I figured out I wasn't completing the group end. (?:dec|oct|sep|aug|jul) https://regex101.com/r/OGqMkL/6  it works! Thank you